# How to manage github repository dependencies while and after contributing to them?

Tags: php, symfony, github, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm using Symfony2 and for my projects I normally do `composer require name/repository` which will install the repository in the `vendor` folder and add a line in the `composer.json` including the package and the installed version.

Supposing that I fork a project because I want to add something to it or fix a bug and use it in my Symfony app, I'd have to run `composer require myname/repository`, modify it, test it and then submit a pull request. Afterwards, after the pull has been commit to the original repository, I'll have to delete my own and remove it from `composer.json` and reinstall the original repository.

Is there a better workflow to this that doesn't have to change the json file that much?

Comment: I'd just edit the composer.json file.   I'd point it to my repo.  That's a minimal headache.  https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Comment: But after that you'd have to change it to point to the original repo and run composer update so it removes your repo and installs the original repo. This is the hassle that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc, you're changing the dependency. That requires changing the files where the dependency is defined (remember to check in `composer.lock` too). I don't see how this is a problem.

Comment: Once the original has been updated you can then update your forked repo so it matches.  That would avoid the need to mess with composer.json at the cost of having to update your repo whenever the original one changes.  But unless you plan on doing a bunch of these changes then it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Or a bit faster way for improving developing process (which is independent on Github), try [using local repositories](http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2014/04/09/php-composer-working-with-local-repositories/).

Comment: Avoid forking just to make your project work. If your PR gets rejected, you end up with plenty of forked repos that you have to maintain, especially tracking important bug fixes from upstream. You should be able to check out the other repo, work on the feature and send a pull request without needing to introduce the change into your own project.

Comment: @Sven then how can I test the repo in a real project if not pulling it into my vendor folder and working with it from there?

Comment: The test case should belong to your pull request, shouldn't it?